# How can I get the number of test iterations in a load test from within a load test plugin?

Tags: c#, load-testing

I need to obtain the number of test iterations for a load test from within a load test plugin, where I have an instance of a `LoadTest` object. I've searched the `LoadTest` object's properties and it feels like there is a lot missing compared to the treeview editor that is normally used to configure a load test.

I'm already defining the number of test iterations again as a Context parameter and passing that through to my web test, but this feels like a hack because I'm duplicating data.

```
class MyLoadTestPlugin : ILoadTestPlugin
{
    private LoadTest loadTest;

    public void Initialize(LoadTest test)
    {
        loadTest = test;

        loadTest.TestStarting += (_, e) =>
        {
            // Get # of Test Iterations in load test here,
            // "loadTest" object does not have nearly as
            // many properties as it should, compared to
            // the tree view editor.
        };
    }     
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the LoadTestPlugin to read the .loadtest file which is a XML file. Here is an example to read the TotalIterations in the .loadtest file.

```
using System;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.LoadTesting;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;

namespace LoadTest
{
    public class LoadTestPluginImpl : ILoadTestPlugin
    {

        LoadTest mLoadTest;

        static int TotalIterations;
        public void Initialize(LoadTest loadTest)
        {
            mLoadTest = loadTest;
            //connect to the TestStarting event.
            mLoadTest.TestStarting += new EventHandler<TestStartingEventArgs>(mLoadTest_TestStarting);
            ReadTestConfig();
        }

        void mLoadTest_TestStarting(object sender, TestStartingEventArgs e)
        {
            //When the test starts, copy the load test context parameters to
            //the test context parameters
            foreach (string key in mLoadTest.Context.Keys)
            {
                e.TestContextProperties.Add(key, mLoadTest.Context[key]);
            }
            //add the CurrentTestIteration to the TestContext
            e.TestContextProperties.Add("TestIterationNumber", e.TestIterationNumber);
            //add the TotalIterations to the TestContext and access from the Unit Test.
            e.TestContextProperties.Add("TotalIterations", TotalIterations);

        }

        void ReadTestConfig()
        {
            string filePath = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, mLoadTest.Name + ".loadtest");

            if (File.Exists(filePath))
            {
                string runSettings = mLoadTest.RunSettings.Name;
                XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
                xdoc.Load(filePath);

                XmlElement root = xdoc.DocumentElement;

                string xmlNameSpace = root.GetAttribute("xmlns");
                XmlNamespaceManager xmlMgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(xdoc.NameTable);
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(xmlNameSpace))
                {
                    xmlMgr.AddNamespace("lt", xmlNameSpace);
                }

                var nodeRunSettings = xdoc.SelectSingleNode(string.Format("//lt:LoadTest/lt:RunConfigurations/lt:RunConfiguration[@Name='{0}']", runSettings), xmlMgr);
                //var nodeRunSettings = xdoc.SelectSingleNode(string.Format("//lt:LoadTest", runSettings), xmlMgr);
                if (nodeRunSettings != null)
                {
                    TotalIterations = Convert.ToInt32(nodeRunSettings.Attributes["TestIterations"].Value);
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Similarly you can read the other values.

Answer (score 1):

A web test has the current iteration number in `webTest.Context.WebTestIteration` (and also as a context parameter named `$WebTestIteration`).

A LoadTest has access to the current iteration number in the `TestStartingEventArgs` object:

```
loadTest.TestStarting += ( (sender, e) =>
{
    int iteration = e.TestIterationNumber;
};
```

---

To prove to myself that these values are the same and that there is no unexpected behaviour like numbers being reused across different scenarios, I **(EDIT:re-)** wrote these plugins, and it checks out.

<sup>(Thanks to @AdrianHHH for pointing out that the previous code was not complete)</sup>

```
public class LoadTestIteration : ILoadTestPlugin
{
    List<int> usedTestIterationNumbers = new List<int>();
    public void Initialize(LoadTest loadTest)
    {
        loadTest.TestStarting += (sender, e) =>
        {
            e.TestContextProperties["$LoadTest.TestIterationNumber"] = e.TestIterationNumber;
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(!usedTestIterationNumbers.Contains(e.TestIterationNumber), "Duplicate LoadTest TestIterationNumber: " + e.TestIterationNumber);
            usedTestIterationNumbers.Add(e.TestIterationNumber);
        };
    }
}

public class TestWebTestIteration : WebTestPlugin
{
    public override void PreWebTest(object sender, PreWebTestEventArgs e)
    {
        int lti = (int)e.WebTest.Context["$LoadTest.TestIterationNumber"];
        int wti = e.WebTest.Context.WebTestIteration;
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(lti == wti, String.Format("$LoadTestIteration {0} differs from $WebTestIteration {1}", lti, wti));
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please clarify how `lastLti` and `lastWti`are updated as the test proceeds.